# Record video in Simulator Xcode 9 Beta

Tags: ios-simulator, video-recording, xcode9-beta

Apple's [Whats new in Xcode 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/xcode_9/xcode_9.html) states that we can record videos of Simulators. How to do that?

Answer (score 46):

Taking a Screenshot or Recording a Video Using the Command Line:

- Launch your app in Simulator.
- Open terminal.

**To take a screenshot**, use the screenshot operation:

```
xcrun simctl io booted screenshot
```

**To record a video**, use the recordVideo operation:

```
xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo <VideoFILENAME>.<extension>
```

To stop recording, press Control-C in Terminal.

> Note: It works only on Mac computers that support Metal
>   . [You can check your PC here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205073).

Comment: Meh. It's easier to launch quicktime:)

Comment: If you record the video this way, it's being saved to your user home folder.

Comment: @balazs630 it records to wherever you tell it to. If you just opened a terminal and the CWD is your home directory and you simply give a filename, then yes, it ends up in the home directory. But you if you've `cd`'d elsewhere or give it more of a path, the video will be where you told it to be.

Comment: Any ideas how to include audio? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'` this error comes up when i use this

Comment: This works great! One thing I noticed was after repeated captures, the quality degraded and the captures became distorted. I think it might have been the OS paging during I/O or some such thing. I tried quitting the simulator but that didn't help. Rebooting my Mac fixed the issue and I was able to capture a clean video again.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS devices you can open control center settings and enable 'recorder' then open control center and tap the circle in circle in control center, to begin recording, when you are done it saves to your photo library. Hope this helps (hope this feature stays on the release version:])

Comment: Thanks @Esyem.  In iOS 11 Simulators I can't see any options in Control Center.